# Is PHP used for quick and easy websites where other languages are used in more complex websites?

Tags: php, website

This stat shows that PHP is used by 75.2% of all the websites whose server-side programming language we know.
http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/programming_language/all

And this page shows that PHP is the least used server-side language in ranked by usage on top websites

http://w3techs.com/technologies/topsite/programming_language

Does this mean PHP is used for quick and easy website where other languages are used in more complex websites?

Answer (score 3):

The language doesn't matter, it's the way you write your application. PHP has got a bad reputation over the years, which is (from my point of view) mainly caused by the bad quality of many scripts, boosted by the simpleness to write your application. (mod_php, wide availability in webhosting packages)
Big sites like Flickr and Facebook are also using PHP (with other languages).
To write a complex site you don't need to go with one technology, often it's better to use other ones ,for some parts, and let them work together to create something awesome ;)